# Cloud Foundry, fetching app events from NATS message bus

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I'm quite new in Cloud Foundry and was curious about one thing. I know that Cloud Foundry uses NATS as its messaging bus between jobs. Being connected to the CF's NATS boxes via Java NATS connector I managed to get a lot of useful information about applications deployed on CF, droplets information, Health Manager report and many more. One of my goals was to request "dea.find.droplet" subject to NATS which causes jobs to return apps' CPU, memory, and disk usage over time.

Now I have to get information about so called "events" from the NATS messages. Using CF CLI tools we can call "cf events APP_NAME" to get this information. A typicals response to "cf events" is something like this

```html
2015-09-15T10:37:35.00-0400   audit.app.update    eadams@covisint.com              state: STARTED
2015-09-03T10:43:08.00-0400   audit.app.restage    troy
2015-08-26T14:26:58.00-0400   app.crash           s-platform          index: 1, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: failed to start, exit_status: -1
```

I already created a maven jar app which runs on remote server, which gathers all the NATS messages, filters them and pushes to the Elastic Search for further analysis.

```html
String reqMessage = "{\"include_stats\": true,"
      //+ "\"states\": [\"RUNNING\"],"
      + "\"version\": \"" + version + "\","
      + "\"droplet\": \"" + droplet + "\"}";


public void requestAppStats(String subject, String reqMessage) throws JSONException{
       // Requests
       //subject: "dea.find.droplet",
       natsConnector.request(subject, reqMessage, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 1, new MessageHandler() {
           @Override
           public void onMessage(Message message) {
               //LOGGER.info("Got a response: {}", message);
            try {
             
             if (new JSONObject(message.getBody()).has("stats")){
          
              updateAppMetaDataList(message.getBody());
          }
             
         } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
           }
       });
```

There is a way to get "events" info from CCDB database instances, but this approach is pretty slow and puts extra burden on the application. So I was wondering is there a way to catch "events" info from NATS messages just like I did with app usage info like this?

```html
natsConnector.request(subject, reqMessage);
```

As you can see in order to get apps' status, resource usage we have to request "dea.find.droplet" with JSON request message.

It would be nice to know what happens when I call "cf events APP_NAME" from CF CLI tools. I looked up the source code of CF CLI tools (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli), which brought me to the CloudController job (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng). Looks like CloudController is in charge of returning app events info. This is pure speculation though.

Maybe at least I could emulate this step to integrate into my app. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Odil, you are right that the Cloud Controller is in charge of events. App events as defined by Cloud Foundry live entirely in the CC database, they are just recorded events when you update/delete/create/etc your app, so they never go through the NATs message bus. I would be interested to hear more specifics on how going through the API is slow.

In general, I wonder why you have a need to connect directly to NATs. App usage statistics can be displayed through the `cf` CLI using `cf app [APPNAME]`. The state of the app is also exposed through the API, e.g. RUNNING/CRASHED/STOPPED.

**Edit:**

[Here is a compiled list](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PHXRc0QAXYPbh88Nu5o60wlsuIddEJhAxiAmiq7NgKk/edit) of all NATs topics that CF uses inside the system. Be aware though, CF is slowly moving away from NATs usage, e.g. the [new Diego runtime](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-release) communicates over HTTP with the Cloud Controller to start/stop applications.

Comment: Initial goal of the application was basically gather all the messages from the NATS boxes and push them to the Elastic Search. I guess we chose to use Java Spring Boot application for this purposes because of the convenience (deploy a jar file, make him as a service, put on crontab and just monitor it once in a while). But then we notice if we request certain subjects we can get some very useful and more importantly relevant info about droplets'/apps' states, which we again can push to the Elastic Search and even visalize it using Kibana's tools, like memory usage over time

Comment: Ran out of characters :)... And I just thought, since we already dealing with whole bunch of NATS messages, it would be nice also gather info about "app events" as well, so later we can provide sufficient statistics about our applications. 
Other reason we chose Java, because it's not Ruby ;)
Our company adopted CF quite recently and we still seeking for useful use-cases for CF and its features. 
As crhino pointed out I could use API calls directly, but the application would be a mix of NATS messages processing logic and RESTful API calls processing logic in that case.

Comment: I edited my post with some more information around NATs topics, hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, crhino. The topics list you posted is incredibly helpful.